# Moving all but one folder to sub-directory - git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a git repo synced with Github with the following structure.

```
~/Data_Store/
~/Data_Read/
....
...
~/R/
```

The .git folder is in ~/

I wish to achieve the following end state.

- The current repo moved to a new folder called ghubrepo in ~/ghubrepo/
- A new repo created linked to BitBucket called bbrepo in ~/bbrepo/
- Retain the ~/R/ folder in ~/ (not synced to any repo)

I have already done the folder structure so it appears as below:

```
~/ghubrepo
~/bbrepo
~/R
~/.git
```

I am now stuck. git status shows all files deleted (except ~/R/) so I dare not commit.

Any suggestions on way fwd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to move the existing repo first in order to avoid a `git status` showing you that "everything is deleted".

```
mkdir ~/ghubrepo
mv ~/* ~/ghubrepo # you might have a warning stating that it cannot move
                  # ghubrepo in itself
mv ~/.git ~/ghubrepo
```

Then you can proceed with the rest of the structure.

But first, check that a `git status` in `~/ghubrepo` is what you expect.